# Select a VBA Pasted Shape from Excel to Word so I can wrap text tight

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm developing a spreadsheet to automatically generate quotes; this involves copying the correct diagram (a grouped Excel shape) from a sheet with a library of our possible diagrams, and pasting/inserting/[whatever will work best] that image into the VBA-assembled Word document.

So far, I am able to successfully identify, copy and paste special the correct diagram shape from Excel into Word. However, every technique I have found means that the shape either wraps text as inline or infront-- whereas I need the next portion of text to be directly aside the diagram-- thus "wdTight"

Below, you can see how I paste in the current shape. But I can't figure out how to make that shape into ".wrapFormat.Type = wdTight"

I am generally met with a series of Runtime 438 errors: object doesn't support this property or method.

I have a theory that this is because Word considers the selection to always be the blinking text cursor, and not the just pasted shape which is activated and has a hovering layout options tooltip (but that is just a theory).

Here is the code. Please help.

```
Sub export_excel_to_word()
Dim appWord
Dim quoteWord
Dim wordSelection

Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWord.Visible = True
Set quoteWord = appWord.Documents.Add
Set wordSelection = appWord.Selection

'This part works
Module1.ImagesRefresh

   'Product 1 image insertion
    Sheets("Quick Lookup").Shapes("QuoteProduct1Image").Copy
    wordSelection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
      DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
      Placement:=wdInLine, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=False

'This part does not work and is where I need help
    With wordSelection
     .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapFront
    End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a variable to represent the newly pasted shape, it should be accessible by index, and should be the last index:

```
   'Product 1 image insertion
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Copy
    wordSelection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
      DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
      Placement:=wdInLine, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=False

    Dim wdShape As Word.Shape
    Set wdShape = quoteWord.Shapes(quoteWord.Shapes.Count)

    wdShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight
```

Without using the shape variable, this might also work, but I have not tested against a document with several shapes (assuming you're adding shapes in sequence/iteration)

```
   'Product 1 image insertion
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Copy
    wordSelection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
      DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
      Placement:=wdInLine, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=False

    wordSelection.ShapeRange(1).WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight
```

If you're *also* inserting text (e.g., through the `TypeText` method of a `Word.Range`, try the code below. I'm not super-familar with Word automation, and the rule that you s[hould avoid activate/select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) I *think* is less strict in Word (or has more exceptions) but as a rule of thumb, I'd still try to avoid reliance on the `Selection` object, and work with ranges instead.

What I'm doing here is pasting to the `wordSelection.Range` rather than the `Selection` itself. Then I do

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Copy
wordSelection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
  DataType:=wdPasteShape, _
  Placement:=wdInLine, _
  DisplayAsIcon:=False
Dim wdShape As Word.Shape
Set wdShape = quoteWord.Shapes(quoteWord.Shapes.Count)
wdShape.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapTight

wordSelection.TypeText "some text"
```

[image]

Comment: That absolutely worked, but my new problem is that as I have VBA type more words, the shape doesn't hold it's position. @DavidZemens do you know how I can fix that shape at the vertical/horizontal position it was pasted? Is there a command I can tack on like 
wdShape.HorizontalPosition = fixed, _ wdShape.VerticalPosition = fixed
?

Comment: @H.Keyser see revised answer. If you have further questions, it's best to ask a new/separate question rather than adding to comments on this answer :)